# Webkit/Firefox - position absolute of image

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-position

H!

I have an issue with the positioning of some elements in webkit-browsers and firefox.

In Safari/Chrome, it looks like I want it to be:

[image]

But in Firefox, it looks like this:

[image]

**Code**

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="#" />
        <p><span class="circle"><img src="white-circle.png" alt="" /></span></p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li {
  position: relative;
}

p {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
}

p img {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -35%;
  margin-left: -35%;
}
```

Any idea what's going on there? Does Firefox interprets the `position: absolute` differently?

Comment: I have tested in Firefox there it works, too.

Comment: dont want to be rude here or offensive so dont misundertand, but this html is a bit of a horror, empty image tag? a p and span around the image? why is a div wrapped around it why dont you give the li the class? everything is in precent, no wonder the browsers not rendering it correctly

Comment: @LeventeNagy Of course you are right, but please keep in mind that this is just an example. I probably oversimplified it, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperently, some other messed up CSS rule was at work there. As a temporary fix I used [this guide](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/) to find a solution working in Firefox.
Probably it's some rule affecting all images, but I could'n find it right now.

Comment: use !important to override those styles

Comment: Naturally, the more specific style that you give to your nodes, overrides the more public ones. Then, there must not make a problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you use absolute positioning firefox seems to always move things differently to Chrome and Safari. My opinion is

```
    p img:{position: relative;}
```

(relative positions is fine its only when i use absolute).

Good Luck